# Are there any studies/theories or papers that address a link between novel environments and psychological well-being?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request

I've been trying to find a reference supporting that new environments without familiar stimuli can cause psychological distress. And prolonged staying in said environment can put a person at risk of anxiety/depression.

It seems intuitive if we assume that familiarity is associated with safety and linked to how positively we view stimuli. (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2948957/) but I haven't found any research about this specific topic. So I was wondering if theres anything glaring Ive missed, which somebody knows about.